# Centering div content within multiple nested divs

Tags: html, css, css-position, centering, grid-layout

I am trying to center some  so that they are displayed within the center, however the tricky part is the html is within a number of  (part of the html is static, and part of it is dynamic from a database).

See the screenshot as an example of how it currently looks (I want this content in the centre)
http://postimg.org/image/5fc6ecgy7/

note - the site is using the base 960 grid system
Below is the HTML:

```
<div class="">
<div class="">
    <div class="">
        <div id="national-prize-feed" class="panel-wrapper ">
            <div class="border">
            <div class="content clearfix add-radius">
            <div style="padding:10px 0px;">
            <div id="nation-prizes-collection" class="clearfix">
            <div class="summary"></div>
            <div class="">
                <div class="national-prizes">
                <div class="prizes">
                    <a href="ipod-shuffle"><img class="prizes-img" alt="iPod Shuffle" src="/images/prizes/ipod-shuffle.png"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="national-prizes">
                <div class="prizes">
                    <a href="football"><img class="prizes-img" alt="Football" src="/images/prizes/football.png"></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="keys" title="/pages/index/slug/prizes" style="display:none">
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

My specific css (there is a lot more.. it is based on a grid based layout)

```
div.prizes {
  float: left;
}

div.prizes img {
  width: 280px;
}

.prizes-img {
  padding: 0 7px 0 7px;
  margin: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to position a DIV to the center of a screen, you need to set a static width of the div to be centered, left: 0px, right: 0px, and the respective margins to auto.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pR4hq/

```
<style>.center{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    background: rgb(90,90,90);
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}</style>
<div class="center">Center Content</div>
```